# Socket.io not connecting to NestJS gateway version 10

Tags: socket.io, nestjs

so im just trying to create a web app which listens on a socket provided by NestJS.

I'm using version 10 of NestJs and i have this dependencies:

```
"@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^10.2.1",
"@nestjs/websockets": "^10.2.1",
"socket.io": "^4.6.0"
```

On the client side im using `"socket.io-client": "^4.6.0"`

My problem is, that the client doesn't connect to the websocket.

I've got a older NestJs (9) project with an gateway. It uses, both @nestjs/platform-socket.io and @nestjs/websockets, in version 9.4.0

If i start this backend my new client is connected immediately.

So i guess my question is: how do i get socket.io to work with an nestjs 10 server?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code today and it works perfectly fine.

```
import {
  WebSocketGateway,
  WebSocketServer,
  SubscribeMessage,
  OnGatewayConnection,
  OnGatewayDisconnect
} from '@nestjs/websockets';

@WebSocketGateway()
export class ChatGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {

  @WebSocketServer() server;
  users: number = 0;

  constructor(
  ) {
  }

  async handleConnection() {
    // A client has connected
    this.users++;

    // Notify connected clients of current users
    this.server.emit('users', this.users);
  }

  async handleDisconnect() {
    // A client has disconnected
    this.users--;

    // Notify connected clients of current users
    this.server.emit('users', this.users);

  }

  @SubscribeMessage('chat')
  async onChat(client, payload) {
    console.log(payload)
    this.client.emit(`chat`, 'response');
  }
}
```

My dependencies on server side are

```
"@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^10.2.4",
"@nestjs/websockets": "^10.2.4",
"socket.io": "^4.7.2",
"socket.io-client": "^4.5.3",
```

I sent a "chat" event from postman using client version v4 and received at server.